# Using SUBSTR and CONCAT to get the required Result

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I Am trying to get the results for the 'CENTRE' whereby if the 'DEP2' does not exist it has to use 'DEP'

Have done this by using SUBSTR and CONCAT in my query
But only get back 3 from 'DEP' when using it like this

My Query:

```
SELECT 
DEP,
DEP2,
SUBSTR(DEP2 || DEP,0,4)CENTRE

FROM DEPARTMENT
```

I Get the results back fine but with 'DEP' only showing 3 numbers instead of the 4

```
----------------------------------
DEP    | DEP2      | CENTRE      | 
----------------------------------
0132    | 7000     | 7000        |
0177    | 7000     | 7000        |
7051    | 7000     | 7000        |
7051    |          |  705        |
7051    |          |  705        | 
----------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If DEP2 is Null then DEP value will be returned

```
SELECT DEP, DEP2, NVL(DEP2, DEP) CENTRE
FROM DEPARTMENT;
```

Comment: Great Thank you it's not taking into account the DEP when DEP2 does not exist the CENTRE returns no results when DEP2 has no data?

Comment: It does return DEP value when DEP2 has no value, have you tried it?

Comment: Ah I found that the DEP2 did not have NULLS I did a TRIM on DEP2 then was able to use the COALESCE. Thanks Very Much !

Answer (score 3):

> if the 'DEP2' does not exist it has to use 'DEP'

Typical `NVL`/`COALESCE` situation, not something that should be handled with string functions.

```
SELECT DEP, DEP2, COALESCE(DEP2, DEP) CENTRE
FROM DEPARTMENT
```